# Android Studio run on Windows 7 64bit fails

Tags: java, android, jvm, android-studio

I had successfully installed Android Studio on Windows 7 64bit , but when I started it , it's not work
and show nothing . Then  I appended the **pause** command to the end of the **studio.bat** .

When I execute via CMD, I get the following error:

> Unrecognized VM option '+UseCodeCacheFlushing'
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

My Jdk version is JDK 1.6

I would like to ask how to solve it?

Comment: What's the output when you run "java -version" from the command prompt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your install directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin
```

and copy the files

```
studio64.exe.vmoptions
studio.exe.vmoptions
```

to your documents.  Edit them and remove the line

```
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
```

in each. Then copy them back to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin
```

and try to relaunch again.

Comment: Awesome it worked after setting JDK_HOME and following above instructions.

Comment: Thanks Dude. Worked successfully after your given settings. +1 for that one.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I have found the solution!

Just update to JDK 1.7!

And Set latest installed JDK path in both JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables.

In my case it is as follows:

- JDK_HOME->C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
- JAVA_HOME->C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Hope it does not work with JDK 1.6 :(

Answer (score 1):

it can be a 64 bit Problem, i had the same problem cause i installed x64 JDK 1.7 didn't work then i installed 32 bit version it worked and installation proceeded. It searches in the system32 folder so 32 bit JDK version is required

Answer (score 0):

Many android developer reported this problem
you can solve it by

1. Right click on My Computer, and select Properties.
2. Click on “Advanced system settings” and go to the “Advanced” tab.
3. On the bottom, click the “Environment Variables” button. This will bring up the Environment Variables screen, you will see two sections, User Variables (at the top), and System Variables (at the bottom).
4. Add a system variable with the name JDK_HOME, and the value equal to the path to your JDK install.